# У приложения на некоторых устройствах нет разрешения на доступ в интернет, несмотря на permission.INTERNET

Tags: android, android-manifest

Тестировал приложение на Sumsung S8 и у приложения не было вообще никаких разрешений. Хотя в манифесте прописано:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Соответственно приложение на одних устройствах имеет доступ, а на каких-то нет, с чем может связано? какие есть решения? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Для устройств с Api >= 23 есть `<uses-permission-sdk-23>`, добавьте в манифест:

```
<uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Официальная документация гласит:

Используя элемент `<uses-permission-sdk-23>` вместо `<uses-permission>`, вы можете запросить разрешение только в том случае, если приложение работает на платформах, поддерживающих модель разрешений среды выполнения, в которой пользователь предоставляет разрешения для приложения пока оно работает.

Подробнее читайте [тут](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-sdk-23-element)